# Why is my score not displaying in Real Time in Sprite Kit?

Tags: xcode5, sprite-kit

I am a brand new developer for Sprite Kit. I am almost done with my first game, yet I am stuck on the code for displaying an ever-changing score in real time. I have spent many days trying my best  and researching for a solution without any results, so I have finally decided to post here in hopes for an answer:

I have created a Score Label Node in myScene and created this Method

```
-(void)adjustScoreBy:(NSUInteger)points 
{

BOOL updateHud = YES;
updateHud += points;
[GameState sharedInstance].score += points;
[scoreLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", [GameState sharedInstance].score]];

}
```

I have created my GameState that works like a Charm and displays both the score and the High Score in my GameOver Scene, BUT it does NOT update the score in real time when I play myScene. Instead it displays the end result of the previous score from the last time I played the game which remains static throughout my entire current game, and I am not able to see the current score until the next GameOver scene again along with the High Score.

Finally, this is my way of calling the update for the score :

```
[self adjustScoreBy:5];
[scoreLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", [GameState sharedInstance].score]];
```

My wish is to be able to display the current score in real time. Please help.

Comment: Have you checked that GameState's score returns the correct value? And where do you call adjustScoreBy from? It needs to be in an update: or repeating block action that runs every frame if you want to update the score in "real time".

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, really appreciated.
Certainly the values are correct in the GameState, I monitor them with the NSLog, and the AdjustScoreBy is called in the Update method.  I know is really strange, maybe the adjustscore method should be improved, I'm really stuck with this and the only thing needed to make the app ready. Thanks again.

Comment: perhaps scoreLabel is nil or not referencing the correct label? Try changing its color for a quick test.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the real time issue by fixing the code as follows:

```
-(void)adjustScoreBy:(NSUInteger)points

{
self.score += points;
SKLabelNode* score = (SKLabelNode*)[self childNodeWithName:kScoreHudName];
score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", (int)self.score];

[GameState sharedInstance].score += points;
   SKLabelNode* scoreLabel = (SKLabelNode*)[self childNodeWithName:kScoreHudName];

[scoreLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", [GameState sharedInstance].score]];

}
```

However, I am faced with a new problem now, my fully working real time score carries to the next game and it adds the new score to the old one…

Comment: I would suggest that modelling your "game state" as a singleton is not the best approach.  If your game consists of a single scene why not make it a property of your scene class.  Assuming you reload your scene when the game starts again you will have a completely fresh state and your score will display correctly.  If that is not an option you will need to reset your GameState when ever a new game  is started.

Comment: [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. (Nobody goes looking at _answers_ to see if they need to be answered!)

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the issue of your score not resetting should be easy if you add a method in your GameState singleton.

Try This:

```
    GameState.h
    -(void)reset; // declare your new method

    GameState.m
    -(void)reset {
        self.score = 0;
    }
```

After your game is over, I would suggest calling a method that would reset your scene within the game scene. This is basically what @nacross is saying, but this way you still use your GameState.

```
    MyScene.m // or whatever your game scene is
    -(void)resetScene {
    [[GameState sharedInstance] reset];
    }
```

This way you keep your singleton, which in my opinion is best practice. For instance, if a player beats a level, you may want to keep their score for the next level.